# Add users to On-Prem Distribution List using PowerShell script - Power Automate Desktop

Tags: powershell, power-automate-desktop

I am new to Power Automate Desktop. I can see that we can run the PowerShell script via Power Automate Desktop.  How to authenticate and add user to On-Prem Distribution List using PowerShell script in Power Automate Desktop?

Comment: Your question is too broad, what have you tried? The PowerShell instance runs with the same privileges as the user or account used for power automate. if you want to authenticate with another user, you need to look at how to do it using PowerShell CLI only.